# get depth map from depth data kinect openni open cv

Tags: c++, opencv, openni

I m beginning in programming with openni and open cv I m working with the kinect .
 here a part of the code that I m using to get de data depth map ( it s working )
Now my question is :
How could I get the depht map as an image in return ?
my data is on DepthPixel* pDepth1 and I want to display the image of the depth map (because I want to save her ).
Thank you

```
VideoFrameRef frame;

DepthPixel* pDepth1 = NULL;
DepthPixel* pDepth2 = NULL;
for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++)
{
    int changedStreamDummy;
    VideoStream* pStream = &depth;
    rc = OpenNI::waitForAnyStream(&pStream, 1, &changedStreamDummy, SAMPLE_READ_WAIT_TIMEOUT);
    if (rc != STATUS_OK)
    {
        printf("Wait failed! (timeout is %d ms)\n%s\n", SAMPLE_READ_WAIT_TIMEOUT, OpenNI::getExtendedError());
        continue;
    }

    rc = depth.readFrame(&frame);
    if (rc != STATUS_OK)
    {
        printf("Read failed!\n%s\n", OpenNI::getExtendedError());
        continue;
    }

    if (frame.getVideoMode().getPixelFormat() != PIXEL_FORMAT_DEPTH_1_MM && frame.getVideoMode().getPixelFormat() != PIXEL_FORMAT_DEPTH_100_UM)
    {
        printf("Unexpected frame format\n");
        continue;
    }

    if (i == 0){
        int dummy;
        cout << "Press any key to take first pic: ";
        cin >> dummy;
        pDepth1 = (DepthPixel*)frame.getData();
    }
    else{
        int dummy;
        cout << "Press any key to take second pic: ";
        cin >> dummy;
        pDepth2 = (DepthPixel*)frame.getData();
    }
```

Comment: As far as I remember, OpenNI delivers kinect depth maps with as 16 Bit unsigned integer, so CV_16U.
Try `cv::Mat depth(frame_height, frame_width, CV_16U, reinterpret_cast<void*>(pDepth1));` . If that works you could save it to disk, but remember to check how OpenCV converts images before saving, maybe you will have to manually convert to CV_8U before (and loose precision) or have to use another library to save the images.

Comment: I don t want to save to the disk i just want to display the result

Comment: do you know how to do this ?
thanks!

Comment: didn't use the kinect with openCV, so I don't know how to get the depth data in that interface. But you could try this
`cv::Mat depthImage(frame_height, frame_width, CV_16U, reinterpret_cast<void*>(pDepth1));`
`cv::namedWindow("depth"); cv::imshow("depth", depthImage); cv::waitKey(-1);'
But I'm not sure what kind of data you get in your depth map. Most probably it should be a 16 bit unsigned integer array, but that's not guaranteed. Have a look at these 2 links too:
http://docs.opencv.org/doc/user_guide/ug_highgui.html
https://github.com/Itseez/opencv/blob/master/samples/cpp/openni_capture.cpp

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you have your dependencies sorted out, the following has worked for me in the past

```
//set up the capture with the correct settings    
VideoCapture capture = new VideoCapture;
capture->open(CV_CAP_OPENNI);
capture->set(CV_CAP_OPENNI_IMAGE_GENERATOR_OUTPUT_MODE, CV_CAP_OPENNI_VGA_30HZ);

//get an image and display it
Mat image;
capture->grab();
capture->retrieve(image, CV_CAP_OPENNI_DEPTH_MAP);
```

then work with the image as you would any other matrix. Remember that the image CV_16U as the capture records depths in 16 bit unsigned integers.